# bootstrap tab contents not working

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

whenever i am trying to load a tab its loading the homepage i am using angularjs as my Js just for the information

```
<div class="container">
  <h1> tab panel </h1>
</div>
<div id="exTab1" class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">test2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">test3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
      <h3>Content's background color is the same for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
      <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
      <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">
      <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

same issue i am facing with the following code also

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help will be appreciated thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide your js ?

Comment: you need more information. put it in jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: Have you used correct script tag like jqurey?

Comment: @UsmanRana i am not using any js for this particular function i mean tab functionality coppied the code from this fiddle where its working perfectly https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

Comment: it seems nothing wrong with the piece of code you provided

Comment: @rbashish yes i have loaded or used the jquery tag on the main index.html file the tab code is wriiten on the view.

Comment: @UsmanRana could it be the issue that agularjs is trying to look <href ="something"> in angular router thats e.g mainapp.js

Answer (score 1):

I tried your second code and its works perfectly !

So :

- did you load jquery.js ?
- did you load bootstrap.js ?
- did you load jquery.js before bootstrap.js ?
- did you load bootstrap.css ?

Comment: all above suggestions loaded perfectly still no luck ,could it be the issue that agularjs is trying to look <href  ="something"> in angular router thats e.g mainapp.js

Comment: Ok, other solution : use ui-bootstrap : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  , easier to use with AngularJs

Comment: That should be ONLY solution - if you use AngularJS use AngularJS and not jQuery stuff.

Comment: Why is it bad practices to mix angular and JQuery ?